# R - for loop to create a vector of values from data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, append

I have a data frame with 15,000 thousand rows for 12 "Days" of observations. One column in this frame has the sums of a value for each day - but this number is the same for 1,000s of rows (each day has a lot of observations). I need to make a vector with the 12 totals and cut the extra stuff.

I did this successfully without a for loop:

```
day1 <- (dat[which(dat$Day == 1), ])[1, 6] # get 1st "Daily.Sum" val of ea. "dat$Day" lev.
day2 <- (dat[which(dat$Day == 2), ])[1, 6] # as "Daily.Sum" is 6th column
day3 <- (dat[which(dat$Day == 3), ])[1, 6]
## ...etc. to "day12"
```

When I use this for loop instead:

```
daysums <- as.numeric()
for (i in 1:12) {
      if (dat$Day == i) {
            daysums <- append(daysums, dat[which(dat$Day == i), ][1, 6])
      }
}
```

I expect to get this:

```
daysums
[1] 979426 1240724 1371640 ...etc. #ea. value = 1st obj. in vector "Daily.Sums" for a 
                                   # given day index in vector "dat$Day"
```

But I get 12 warnings:

```
12: In if (dat$Day == i) { ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Clearly my for loop logic is flawed here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the split function

```
split(Dat,Dat$day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `with(dat,{tapply(Daily.Sum,Day,mean)})`